# Simplest way to use REST service

Tags: objective-c, ios, rest

What is the simplest and easiest way, not the best way, to use a REST web service in an iPhone app? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best I have found so far is as follows:

1. Use the very excellent ASIHTTPRequest helper class from http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/
2. Use JSON for your request and response, and parse with http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

I just added the above classes to my project, and include them where necessary. Then:

```
NSURL *url = @"http://example.com/rest/whatever";

// create dictionary with post data
NSMutableDictionary *requestDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[requestDict setObject: Id forKey:@"Id"];
[requestDict setObject: field.text forKey:@"Name"];

//Prepare the http request
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL: url]; 
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"raw"];
[request setPostBody: [NSMutableData dataWithData: [[[self sbjson] stringWithObject:requestDict] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
[request startSynchronous];
[requestDict release];

self.error = [request error];

if(self.error)
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(serviceConnectionDidFail) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
else
{
    // request succeeded - parse response
    NSDictionary *responseDict = [self.sbjson objectWithString:[request responseString]];
    int value = [responseDict valueForKey:@"ServerValue"];
}
```

Its really simple, reliable, and good error handling.

Comment: Thank you very much. The exemple look simple . But my webservice is with GET method .It's somethink like this .http://85.17.168.204:8080/TunisairRESTful/resources/cities/ 

Have you an exemple please ?

Comment: Change the request's RequestMethod to @"GET", and omit the PostBody. 

Read the getting started guide here for more: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Answer (score 0):

Open safari and navigate to the appropriate URL for the REST server.

Comment: Rob - I don't mean to be rude when I ask - is this is an actual answer, or are you are making a joke? Is this really possible? How do you post data to the server, and how do you parse the response?

Comment: Ryan, it was a half-joke but it does completely satisfy the OP's stated question which did not specify what operations were required when communicating with a REST server.

Comment: it's a joke or you are serious ?

Comment: siMonAkro, please disregard my answer. I was answering your initial question *as stated* and while it is true that the *simplest*, *easiest* way to use a REST web service from an iPhone app is to use Safari to retrieve information from it's published URI, I doubt this will satisfy your needs. Sorry for the confusion.